# Adding data to an existing XML file on Android

Tags: android, xml

i have an XML file located at /res/xml that i made which contains some tags.
i would like to add data(tags) in the xml file at specific places like after searching for a certain tag adding some text afterwards.

```
<set>test1
    <subset>bla</subset>
        <subset>bla1</subset>
            ....
            ....
</set>

    <set>test2
        .....
    </set>
```

for instance after finding test1 i would like to add to the end of the test1 tag a subcat tag like bla4

tried XmlSerializer  with no luck...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify resources at runtime. At best, you can copy the XML from the resource to the local filesystem, then work with that file.